# React. Redux-persist v6. Отложенная регидрация или как загрузить из хранилища после авторизации?

Tags: reactjs, redux, persistence

Есть корневой редьюсер- состоит из множества комбинированных

```
const authTransform = createTransform(
  (inboundState: IAccount) => ({ id: inboundState.id }),
  (outboundState: IAccount) => outboundState,
  { whitelist: ['account'] }
);

const authConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['account'],
  transforms: [authTransform],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers<IRootState>({
  authentication: persistReducer<AuthenticationState>(authConfig, authentication),
  .. 50+ редьюсеров
```

делаю на него обертку

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: [
    'myReducer1',
    'myReducer2'
  ],
  blacklist: ['authentication'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const reducerPersist = persistReducer<IRootState>(persistConfig, reducer);

export default reducerPersist;
```

store:

```
const initialize = (initialState?: IRootState, middlewares = []) => {
  const store = createStore(reducerPersist, initialState, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...defaultMiddlewares, ...middlewares)));
  const persistor = persistStore(store, null, () => {});
  return { store, persistor };
};

export default initialize;
```

также добавлены

при рендере компонента в componentDidMount запускается  запрос что пользователь авторизован и следующий получает какой именно пользователь (вся авторизация через keycloack)
при старте происходит регидрация польователя потом регидрация данных. и летят паачками fetch запросы для редьюсеров  т.к. мне важен последний результат склеиваю ...state и ...action.payload.data и делаю lodash _.merge. чтобы заменить загруженные поля с пустыми значениями на сохраненные.
пробловала обнулять данные с помощью reset-persist или state=undefined. но у меня параллельно после получения пользователя идет рендеринг  дочерних компонентов и получается пока доходит откат гидрации стейты уже частично обновляются в итоге при октате  падают ошибки.
Если выйти и зайти под другим пользователем то  грузятся сохраненные данные другого пользователя.

```
persist/PERSIST
persist/REHYDRATE
persist/REHYDRATE
authentication/IS_AUTHENTICATED_PENDING
locale/SET_LOCALE
loading-bar/HIDE
authentication/IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULFILLED
loading-bar/SHOW
authentication/GET_SESSION_PENDING
```

Как я могу отключить регидрацию пока не будет загружен пользователь и запросить ее позже?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать через persistoid

```
  const persistoid = createPersistoid(config);
  store.subscribe(() => {
    persistoid.update(store.getState());
  });
```